# Split a polygon into smaller parts without using Split

Tags: arcmap, splitting

Is there an alternative to split in ArcMap 10.4, if you don't have the advanced license?

What I want to do is split a polygon according to another polygon. I want to preserve the extent of the original polygon but have it be divided into smaller parts.

In the image below, the underlying polygon (looks like a raster but is a polygon) should be divided according to the borders (white lines) of the overlying polygon.

[image]

With the Clip tool, you extract parts of the polygon instead of just splitting it, so that doesn't seem like an option.

Comment: Have you tried Intersect tool?

Comment: No. That did _exactly_ what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool should do what you want:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.

Comment: This works very well. Thank you.